# Does bleeding break the fast?

Tags: fiqh, sawm

I have heard that bleeding invalidates the fast. This could be from a minor cut from a knife or from a severe accident.

What is the exact ruling about this?

What about minor bleeding caused by popping of a pimple, nose bleeding for no obvious reasons or blood in the stool?

Answer (score 7):

[image: In the name of Allah, The Most Beneficent, The Most Merciful]

If bleeding did invalidate fast, our beloved Prophet (Peace and mercy of Allah be upon him) would never undergo cupping while fasting.

> ### Sahih Al-Bukhari
>
> #### [Book 30 (Fasting) :: Hadith 45](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/45)
>
> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>
> The Prophet (pbuh) was cupped while he was in the state of lhram, and also while he was observing a fast.
>
> #### [Book 30 (Fasting) :: Hadith 46](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/46)
>
> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>
> The Prophet (pbuh) was cupped while he was fasting.
>
> #### [Book 76 (Medicine) :: Hadith 16](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/76/16)
>
> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>
> The Prophet (pbuh) was cupped while he was fasting.

Cupping/Hijama is a process that sucks blood through a small incision made in a person's skin.

If you don't know what cupping is, go through **[this page from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijama)**.

However, Hanbali school debates that Cupping invalidates the fast, **NOT** due to the flow of blood, but because of the temporary weakness it offers. This is albeit a different question you could ask.

One thing you should obviously be cautious is that when nasal or oral bleeding occurs, maximum care should be taken not to let the blood down the throat.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Comment: +1 for hadith reference and explaining cupping.

Answer (score 5):

What invalidates the fast is [bloodletting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodletting) or cupping. This is because of the following [narration](http://sunnah.com/urn/2059160) from the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam)

> Shaddad bin Aus (Radiallahu anhu) narrated that The Messenger of Allah
>   (salallahu alayhi wassalam) came across a man in Al-Baqi' (in Madinah)
>   who was having himself cupped in Ramadan., and said to him, “The one
>   who cups and the one who is being cupped have both broken their fast."
>   Related by the five Imams except for At-Tirmidhi. Ahmad, Ibn Khuzaimah
>   and Ibn Hibban regarded it as authentic.

Scholars use the same hadeeth to conclude that intentional blood leaving like donating blood or treatment by letting blood out will also invalidate the fast.

However, blood exiting from a fasting person unintentionally does not break the fast because he is excused for that. Examples being nosebleed or the blood from surgery or a tooth extraction.

[Lessons in Fasting - Shaykh Salih Al-Fawzaan](http://abdurrahman.org/ramadhan/Lessons-Fasting-Fawzan/)

On the side note, there is disagreement on this issue. Majority of the scholars view cupping in Ramadhaan as permissible because of other Hadeeths that state that the Prophet sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam was cupped while he was fasting. You can read a detailed treatment of the issue [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=articles&id=154211).

Comment: +1, Thanks for posting the scholarly opinion. I wasn't aware of it. Jazaakallah

Comment: @TabrezAhmed wa iyyak. However, there is ikhtillaf in this issue. Like you mentioned. Majority of the scholars say it is permissible including three of the four madhhabs. However, to be on the safe side, one can try to avoid cupping in Ramadhaan.

Comment: @Abdullah looks like there is no rule. According to Dr Ali Ahmad, donating blood while fasting does not break fast.[link](http://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/ramadan-question-is-it-permitted-to-wear-make-up-during-the-holy-month-2013-08-03-1.513663) `Does blood donation break the fast?
 
Dr Ali Ahmed says:
In case a person donates blood during the day in Ramadan, the fast does not break.`

Comment: It seems like, fron the hadith, he reason for the fast being broken by cupping is not related to the flow of blood, as the fast  of the person doing cupping is also invalidated.

Comment: @Ifoundthetruth As I mentioned in my answer, there is a disagreement in this issue and it seems, Dr Ali Ahmed has the other opinion.

Comment: @goto It is related to flow of blood. That is how the scholars interpret it. The fast of the person doing cupping is also invalidated because he is doing something he is not supposed to do while fasting.

Comment: @Abdullah: Swearing is not something that you are not suppose to during fasting, but doing so, does not breaks the fast.

Comment: @goto But cupping does because Prophet(salallahu alayhi wassalam) said so.

Comment: @goto Maybe you will find this useful - "As for the one who does cupping, his fast is annulled too, because he may swallow some blood [during the process]. However, if one does cupping using modern equipment, rather than his mouth, then the procedure does not render his fast null and void." - http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=articles&id=154211