# Does bleeding make a fast void

Tags: sawm

Does during fasting makes it void. Does it depend on the amount of bleeding or the type bleeding. I need full details about it.

Comment: just to add up what Goldprsuedo has said, if the bleeding is inside the mouth, as long as you dont swallow it, your fast is valid..

Comment: Found a similar question here : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/does-bleeding-break-the-fast For those who like a little more detailed discussion and various Sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bleeding, as in bleeding from a cut or a wound, does not make the fast void in and of itself.  If, however, the blood loss is enough to weaken you to the point that further fasting would actually be *harmful* to your health, the fast should be broken; this would fall under the same general ruling as breaking your fast due to illness and making it up at a later date.

However, in the case of women where the bleeding is menstrual or post-natal blood, the fast is considered void.  Again, this would need to be made up at a later date.