# Hemorrhoids and Ramadan

Tags: sawm, ramadan, authenticity

I have a really bad case of hemorrhoids and constipation currently. I am wondering that if a lot of blood comes out with the bowel movements, will my fast be invalidated? I can't really control if I bleed (usually always bleeds) or when I have to go to the washroom.

Comment: Note that if you are ill or have medical problems, the general consensus is that you are exempt from fasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamu Alaikum

To begin with, first I'd recommend you to visit a good [gastroenterologist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenterology) because [your condition](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/blood-in-stool) is not to be neglected and should be dealt seriously.

To simply answer your question, **No, even if lot of blood comes out from stool, your fast will not be invalidated** ([Sunni View](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/does-bleeding-break-the-fast)).

Next, my recommendations for you to fast or not to fast would depend on where you live. Because with these serious health problems, if it turns out that the duration of fast (in your place) is too long to be bearable by you, you could seriously worsen your health condition. Supposing that the duration of fast (duration of daylight) in your place is less than say, 14 hours or so, then under some conditions you can safely fast.

Those conditions are nothing but, during the night (i.e. not while fasting)

- Break up your meals and have them in small quantities so that you don't develop ulcer or the like diseases.
- Make sure you have enough fiber rich foods and plenty of water (fluids) to deal with constipation.
- Also recommended (until you visit the doctor) is have enough multi vitamins and [pre and probiotics](http://chriskresser.com/5-uncommon-uses-for-probiotics/) and a good nutritional diet.
- Exercise enough, regularly, to beat [hemorrhoids](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en-IN&q=deal%20with%20hemorrhoids) and constipation.

Comment: Thank you for that relieving answer. I have had hemorrhoids for a couple of years now and constipation usually comes and goes. The fast over here is 17-18 hours. I went to the doctor recently too and he just gave me an ointment, so I'll have to visit a gastroenterologist as you said but i think I'll continue the fasting for now.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is no, it will not invalidate your fast.

**Intentional** blood leaving like donating blood or treatment by letting blood out will invalidate the fast. However, blood exiting from a fasting person **unintentionally** does not break the fast because he/she is excused for that. Examples being nosebleed or the blood from surgery or a tooth extraction.

## Recommendations

- Drink plenty of **water** to prevent constipation from fasting
- When not fasting, eat **fiber supplement** to prevent constipation from fasting
- Try **Calmovil**. See [calmovil.com](http://calmovil.com) They have drops, supplement, and cream for hemorrhoids.