# Does sperm release due to wet dreams invalidate fasts?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, nocturnal-emission

Today morning I had a bad experience in my life and now I want to understand whether is it ghuna or not. I didn't eat anything in sahri I slept without doing sehari and after that I had a bad dream and my sperm was released automatically. When I woke up in morning I found this out, so I don't no what to do now as is it ghuna or what exactly it is as I didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: sorry brother i dint get suficent time to see all the  quotation.

Answer (score 0):

> dear all i hope all is well,
>
> today morning i had bad experience in my life and now i want to
>   understand whether is it ghuna or not, i dint had anything in sahri i
>   slept without doing sehari and after that i had bad dream and my sperm
>   was released automatically. when i woke up in morning i found this so
>   i dont no what to do now as is it ghuna or what exactly it is as i
>   dint do it intentionally.

What you had is a wet dream. Sperm release due to wet dreams do not invalidate fasts. So, your fast is not broken.

Comment: thank you mohammad as i was realy nervous and i thought i need to feed 60 people  i no the punishment for this and i realy got scared .

Comment: and one more thing i had some skin  issues wich are not that much big but you can say bit kind small wonde and i dont have any problems with that but is it possible that my fast is broken by that.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum and welcome to Islam.SE. Cupping/bleeding/wonds due to skin diseases don't invalidate the fast. But if you intentionally bleed youself then the fast is broken. For more read this, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/does-bleeding-break-the-fast